# Why The Query Against HashKey returns no records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hashbytes

I am working on a new sql table. The table has a column [varbinary(8000)], where we are storing hash of a certain text. Now, I am trying to retrieve the same record back by using a where clause against the hashkey, but that yields zero records.

I have added a similar query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be996/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the single quotes, like this

```
SELECT id, description
FROM ForgeRock
where id = 0x94EE059335E587E501CC4BF90613E0814F00A7B08BC7C648FD865A2AF6A22CC2
```

and you will get the expected result.

Comment: Ar it was the strange format sqlfiddle uses that confused me - you can't remove the quotes from that 'lO4FkzXlh+UBzEv5BhPggU8Ap7CLx8ZI/YZaKvaiLMI='